# Changing log level for Tomcat does not work

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I am trying to configure Log4j on Tomcat, so here is my config:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.ibatis=INFO
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource=INFO
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner=INFO
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientDelegate=INFO
log4j.logger.java.sql=INFO
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=INFO
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=INFO
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=INFO
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=INFO

# Thymeleaf logger
log4j.logger.org.thymeleaf=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.CONFIG=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.TIMER=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.PARSERCACHE=ERROR
```

I want to have only info level of logs, and Thymeleaf configured to display only errors. But I am still getting this info in catalina.out:

```
00:43:44.591 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
00:43:44.591 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG c.p.app.interceptors.UserInterceptor - ================= addToModelUserDetails ============================
00:43:44.593 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG c.p.app.interceptors.UserInterceptor - ================= addToModelUserDetails ============================
00:43:44.593 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@2874f679] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
00:43:44.593 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-bio-8080-exec-2] STARTING PROCESS OF TEMPLATE "dashboard/index" WITH LOCALE pl_PL
00:43:44.594 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository - [THYMELEAF][http-bio-8080-exec-2] Template "dashboard/index" was correctly resolved as resource "/WEB-INF/pages/dashboard/index.html" in mode LEGACYHTML5 with resource resolver "SERVLETCONTEXT"
00:43:44.610 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-bio-8080-exec-2] Starting process on template "dashboard/index" using mode "LEGACYHTML5"
00:43:44.610 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository - [THYMELEAF][http-bio-8080-exec-2] Template "template/template" was correctly resolved as resource "/WEB-INF/pages/template/template.html" in mode LEGACYHTML5 with resource resolver "SERVLETCONTEXT"
00:43:44.625 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0'
00:43:44.625 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0'
00:43:44.625 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0'
00:43:44.626 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0'
00:43:44.663 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-bio-8080-exec-2] Finished process on template "dashboard/index" using mode "LEGACYHTML5"
00:43:44.674 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-bio-8080-exec-2] FINISHED PROCESS AND OUTPUT OF TEMPLATE "dashboard/index" WITH LOCALE pl_PL
00:43:44.674 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.TIMER - [THYMELEAF][http-bio-8080-exec-2][dashboard/index][pl_PL][80456234][80] TEMPLATE "dashboard/index" WITH LOCALE pl_PL PROCESSED IN 80456234 nanoseconds (approx. 80ms)
00:43:44.674 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
00:43:44.678 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
00:43:44.678 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Any clue? I know that mistake might be very silly, but I am searching for answer quite a long time ;) Thanks :)

Comment: A common reason is that another log4j config file is present somewhere in classpath which is getting picked. Please check.

Comment: There is only one:
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/[app-name]/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the properties file that would deliberately enable debug level logging. Suggest that you go back to your catalina.out file and verify that the log4j.properties file was parsed without error upon startup. Also have a look at the logging.properties file in the CATALINA_HOME/conf folder and verify that all of the logging there is at level CONFIG or lower.